# How can i modify registry via c# on win7?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, proxy, windows-7, registry

I modify my WIN7 computer's registry via c#,but it dosen't work.
[image]
my code likes below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;          //添加针对操作注册表的应用  

namespace operateToolWPF.Utils
{
class RegisterHelper
{
    public static string GetRegistryData(RegistryKey root, string subKey, 
string name)
    {
        string registData = string.Empty;
        RegistryKey myKey = root.OpenSubKey(subKey, true);
        if (myKey != null)
        {
            registData = myKey.GetValue(name).ToString();
        }
        return registData;
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// 向注册表中写数据  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="root"></param>  
    /// <param name="subKey"></param>  
    /// <param name="keyName"></param>  
    /// <param name="keyValue"></param>  
    public static void SetRegistryData(RegistryKey root, string subKey, string keyName, Int32 keyValue)
    {
        RegistryKey aimDir = root.CreateSubKey(subKey);
        aimDir.SetValue(keyName, keyValue, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// 删除注册表中指定的注册项  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="root"></param>  
    /// <param name="subKey"></param>  
    /// <param name="keyName"></param>  
    public static void DeleteRegist(RegistryKey root, string subKey, string keyName)
    {
        string[] subkeyNames;
        RegistryKey myKey = root.OpenSubKey(subKey, true);
        subkeyNames = myKey.GetSubKeyNames();
        foreach (string aimKey in subkeyNames)
        {
            if (aimKey == keyName)
                myKey.DeleteSubKeyTree(keyName);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>  
    /// 判断指定注册表项是否存在  
    /// </summary>  
    /// <param name="root"></param>  
    /// <param name="subKey"></param>  
    /// <param name="keyName"></param>  
    /// <returns></returns>  
    public static bool IsRegistryExits(RegistryKey root, string subKey, string keyName)
    {
        bool result = false;
        string[] subKeyNames;
        RegistryKey myKey = root.OpenSubKey(subKey, true);
        subKeyNames = myKey.GetValueNames();
        foreach (string name in subKeyNames)
        {
            if (name == keyName)
            {
                result = true;
                return result;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

}

and then call it like this:

```
//获取当前Windows用户  
        WindowsIdentity curUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        //用户SID  
        SecurityIdentifier sid = curUser.User;
        //用户全称  
        NTAccount ntacc = (NTAccount)sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
        Console.WriteLine("Windows SID:" + sid.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("用户全称:" + ntacc.Value);
        Int32 tempInt = 0; //预先定义一个有符号32位数
        //unchecked语句块内的转换，不做溢出检查
        unchecked
        {
            tempInt = Convert.ToInt32("00000000", 16); //强制转换成有符号32位数
        }
        //读取Display Inline Images  
        string displayImgPath = sid.Value + @"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings";
        string ProxyEnable = RegisterHelper.GetRegistryData(Registry.Users, displayImgPath, "ProxyEnable");
        //此时的tempInt已经是有符号32位数，可以直接写入注册表
        RegisterHelper.SetRegistryData(Registry.Users, displayImgPath, "ProxyEnable", tempInt);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        RegisterHelper.DeleteRegist(Registry.Users, displayImgPath, "ProxyServer");
        RegisterHelper.DeleteRegist(Registry.Users, displayImgPath, "ProxyOverride");
        Registry.Users.Close();
        Process[] MyProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        MyProcess[0].Kill();
```

by all this ,i want modify ProxyEnable and delete ProxyOverride,ProxyServer,which was cancel IE proxy setting.

I have tried several methodes,but have no one can cancel IE proxy setting.
Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I would implement registry IO as you have tried to do.  Depending on which part of the registry you are trying to read/write from may use different keys:

```
    public class MyReg{
    public RegistryKey Foriegnkey {
        get => forignKey;
        set => forignKey = value;
    }
    private RegistryKey forignKey;

    public object Read(string Path, string Name) => (Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(Path, false).GetValue(Name));

    public void Write(string Path, string Name, object Data) {
        Foriegnkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(Path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
        Foriegnkey.SetValue(Name, Data);
        Foriegnkey.Close();
    }
  }
```

The example above will read / write at Current User level, but there are other levels which can be used, and you will see these as available options within IntelliSense

You can use this in your application by assigning an instance of your registry class to an object and just calling registry.read/write etc …

This can be checked for nulls using :

```
    if (Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MyApp", "SomeValue", null) == null)
```

And when you come to write data you can use:

```
    myregobject.Write(@"\software\MyApp", "SomeValue", "hello world!");
```

In your case this enables you to do the following:

```
    if (!Registry.GetValue(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", "ProxyEnable", null) == null) {
       myregobject.Write(@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", "ProxyEnable", "your data here")
    }
```

I cant tell if your delete method works or not from looking at it so i'll throw in my input there as well:

```
    public void RemoveKey(string FolderName) {
        Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree(FolderName);
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help ! But ot doesen't work,and trow exception:System.ArgumentException: 注册表项名称必须以有效的基项名称开头。?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what it is exactly that you want to do?  step by step.  I can add another code sample based on this to ensure that the code works for you :)

Comment: I developed a WPF application that uses the fiddlercore API provided by the proxy tool Fiddler to capture HTTP request data. Finally, using the Doquit () method provided by fiddlercore API, the agent is closed, although the agent is closed, but C# is used to make the post request at this point, and the Internet cannot be connected.
So now I want to use the code to force the EnableProxy fields in the registry to be modified.

Comment: What is root node containing the key "\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ?  

Also - what is the purpose of:

`asdf
        Int32 tempInt = 0; //预先定义一个有符号32位数
        //unchecked语句块内的转换，不做溢出检查
        unchecked
        {
            tempInt = Convert.ToInt32("00000000", 16); //强制转换成有符号32位数
        }`

In order to force the EnableProxy fields what value needs to be inserted?

Comment: The root node is HKEY_CURRENT_USER。The reason for the conversion to 16 hexadecimal is that the registry is stored in sixteen hexadecimal numbers.Even if it is not 16 hexadecimal, it will not lead to errors.